# Fast count of number of Events for each Object with R data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a number of Objects that can be within a number of locations (where the number of locations is considerably smaller then the number of objects), each object has a start and an end date. I also have a number of Events, which also have a location, and a day on which they occur. I want to know for each Object the number of Events that occured at the same location during their stay (so that occur between the object's start and end date).

As I have several sets and the number of objects differs from 450.000 to 6 million, this task takes considerable time. Until now, the fastests method I found uses the data.table method. The function below shows an example of this where you can vary the number of sizes.

```
coupleEventObject <- function(sizeO=100,sizeE=100){
 require(data.table)
 require(zoo)

 #create the events  
 Events <- data.table(EventNumber = c(1:sizeE),
                      Location    = as.character(sample(c(1:floor(sizeO/10)),size=sizeE,replace=T)),
                      DayEvent    = rand.day(day.start="2007-01-01",
                                     day.end  ="2015-12-31",
                                     size=sizeE))

 #Create the objects
 Objects <- data.table(ObjectNumber = c(1:sizeO),
                       Location     = as.character(sample(c(1:floor(sizeO/10)),size=sizeO,replace=T)),
                       Day1 = rand.day(day.start="2007-01-01",
                                          day.end  ="2015-12-31",
                                          size=sizeO),
                       Day2 = rand.day(day.start="2007-01-01",
                                         day.end  ="2015-12-31",
                                         size=sizeO))

 Objects[, DayStart := as.Date(ifelse (Day1>Day2,Day2,Day1))]
 Objects[, DayEnd   := as.Date(ifelse (Day1<Day2,Day2,Day1))]
 Objects[,c("Day1","Day2"):=NULL]

 #Set keys right for the coupling/counting
 setkey(Objects,Location,DayStart,DayEnd)
 setkey(Events,Location,DayEvent)

 #Count the number of events
 system.time(
 Objects[,NumberEvents:=Events[Location,][DayEvent >= DayStart & DayEvent <= DayEnd,.N],by=list(DayStart,DayEnd,Location)]
 )
}

rand.day <- function(day.start,day.end,size) {
  dayseq <- seq.Date(as.Date(day.start),as.Date(day.end),by="day")
  dayselect <- sample(dayseq,size,replace=TRUE)
  return(dayselect)
}
```

For 100 Objects and 100 Events this code runs on my laptop within 0.3 seconds

```
> coupleEventObject()
   user  system elapsed 
   0.30    0.00    0.29
```

But if I increasy the number of objects this scales almost linearly with the process time.

```
> coupleEventObject(sizeE=200,sizeO=6000)
   user  system elapsed 
  15.11    0.00   15.26
```

So to count the number of Events for 6 million objects this costs about 4 hours, and I have to do this several times (different kind of location levels and). Is there a way to speed this up? Thanks for your help and ideas!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy that function, now it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option. The main idea is to join the Events and Objects in such way that every combination exist first, and then just count the valid values. As you will see, the new way runs by far faster and you get the same results.
Btw... You might have to change the random date generator because I didn't have access to your original function.

```
coupleEventObject1 <- function(sizeO=100,sizeE=100){
 require(data.table)
 require(zoo)

 #create the events  
 Events <- data.table(EventNumber = c(1:sizeE),
                      Location    = as.character(sample(c(1:floor(sizeO/10)),size=sizeE,replace=T)),
                      DayEvent    = as.Date(as.integer(runif(sizeE)*1000)))

 #Create the objects
 Objects <- data.table(ObjectNumber = c(1:sizeO),
                       Location     = as.character(sample(c(1:floor(sizeO/10)),size=sizeO,replace=T)),
                       Day1 = as.Date(as.integer(runif(sizeE)*1000)),
                       Day2 = as.Date(as.integer(runif(sizeE)*1000)))

 Objects[, DayStart := as.Date(ifelse (Day1>Day2,Day2,Day1))]
 Objects[, DayEnd   := as.Date(ifelse (Day1<Day2,Day2,Day1))]
 Objects[,c("Day1","Day2"):=NULL]

 #Set keys right for the coupling/counting
 setkey(Objects,Location,DayStart,DayEnd)
 setkey(Events,Location,DayEvent)

 #Count the number of events
 cat("First method:")
 cat(system.time(
 res1 <- Objects[,NumberEvents:=Events[Location,][DayEvent >= DayStart & DayEvent <= DayEnd,.N],by=list(DayStart,DayEnd,Location)]
 ))
 cat("\n")


 ## second method

 #Set keys right for the coupling/counting
 setkey(Objects,Location)
 setkey(Events,Location)

 #Count the number of events
 cat("Second method:")
 cat(system.time({
 oe <- Objects[Events,allow.cartesian=T]
 res2 <- oe[,sum(DayEvent >= DayStart & DayEvent <= DayEnd),by=list(ObjectNumber,DayStart,DayEnd,Location)]
 }))
 cat("\n")

 # comparing
 setkey(res1, ObjectNumber, Location, DayStart, DayEnd)
 setkey(res2, ObjectNumber, Location, DayStart, DayEnd)
 cat("Compare values: ", nrow(res1[res2][NumberEvents != V1,])," mismatches\n")

 return(list(res1=res1,res2=res2))
}
```

and here the results:

```
xx <- coupleEventObject1(200,6000)
First method:8.151 0.041 8.15 0 0
Second method:0.614 0.017 0.625 0 0
Compare values:  0  mismatches
```

Comment: Thank you, this method indeed scales much better, for my problems it will be more then 100 times faster.